# Very Slow App Upload/Communication Failure - Application Loader

Tags: application-loader

I have been using application loader since one year. But for last few months I have problems with the application loader.

When I click on the send button in the Application loader it shows Authenticating with iTunes Store. This authentication step takes around 5 minutes. After that it shows communicating with iTunes Store for around 10-15 mins and then throws up a communication error:

```
Communication Error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need
to have outbound access to TCP Port 443.

An exception has occurred:Operation timed out. Could not connect to Apple's web
service.

An error occurred while connecting to the transport host https://itmsdav.apple.com:
Operation timed out.

Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics.
```

I tried googling and many told me there will be firewall/Java issues. I checked that. There is no firewall turned on or any issues with other Java Application. Its just the problem with my Application loader.

I tried uploading the application from my college, and it works there perfectly. But at my home it throws this error always.

The only difference is that In my college I just plug in my ethernet cable and access Internet and at my home its like a ADSL Modem which needs a PPP connection established. I also found out that the Application loader sends out UDP packets.

Will the problem be in my ADSL Modem? Does anybody have similar problems?

Comment: yes i have similar problem.and dont know how to solve it.

Comment: I stuck at authenticating with ituens... But I switch to use the organiser, it uploaded the app in 10 seconds. I guess the application loader is not suitable to upload app.

Comment: Please visit here, I solved it Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540054/xcode-build-upload-error-outbound-access-to-tcp-port-443-and-unable-to-find-a-m/55085319#55085319

Answer (score 8):

Be sure you don't have Charles proxy running as well (or any proxying software). I was bitten by this and took a couple of hours before I figured out it was Charles swallowing all the requests :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Application Loader uses Java, and Java does not inherit the Mac's proxy settings. The solution is to specify the proxy information to Java.

If you are on a Mac OS pre-10.7.5 (more or less) just look for the Java Preferences application via the spotlight. If not, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849760/mac-os-x-socks-proxy-environment-variable) specifies how to do so.

Comment: im on OS X ML, does this still works? i having the same problem

Comment: Normally yes, but if you are behind a corporate firewall you might want to check first you are allowed to access the necessary ports.

Comment: sorry newbie here, where can i check my mac firewall?

Comment: ow, i just found the firewall settings and its turned off but still im having slow upload.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many solutions like using port 80 for https connection but none of the solution worked for me.

```
#https.proxyPort=443
```

to

```
https.proxyPort=80
```

Changing port didn't work for me.

After many trying many solutions I tried to upload application from two different instances of application loader and it worked like a charm.

I have two different versions of application loader on my machine, one came with XCode4 and one came with XCode5. It always works if I upload application from two instances simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, after trying for 2 times with 2 instance of application loader, I could be able to submit for review.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i was using Charles Proxy. So, i closed the CHarles Proxy and able to upload.

Comment: Thanks a million. This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line in my bash_profile worked for me

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080 -DsocksProxyHost=my-socks-server"
```

- Xcode 5.1.1 (5B1008)
- Yosemite Beta
- java version "1.6.0_65"

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with same problem while uploading my first application. After trying so many changes nothing worked out fine for me.

Finally I changed Application Loader version. That's it. Worked fine for me. I used Application Loader 2.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem despite trying all the suggestions in the thread.
Running App Loader 2.9.1; Java version 7 build 1.7.0.; Yosemite beta 4; Xcode 5.1.1.
Also tried all the settings in Java Control Panel General/Network Settings. All firewall ports open for outbound traffic.

Any further suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of unsuccessful tries, I went to System Preferences -> Network -> Proxies and enabled "Auto Proxy Discovery". Worked like a charm afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you do **not** have mentioned [Charles proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) and the error with uploading came from "nowhere" then try to simply change network **and** restart your Mac. In my case doing those **two** did the job, changing just network did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Preference -> Network -> Advanced -> Proxies -> Deselect proxies" if anything selected.

Note: If you want to cross check it, open apple developer account in browser. If it's loaded, this error won't come.

[image]