# Mac OS X socks proxy environment variable

Tags: macos, command-line, proxy, environment-variables

I know it's possible to set the socks proxy server via network app and there is a Mac specific utility to set it but I prefer to just set the socks proxy server as an environment variable if possible. Does anyone know the appropriate `export` setting?

In case anyone is wondering this is possible for http proxy, for example, `export http_proxy=http://my-proxy-server:1080/` get picked up by the JVM as `http.proxyPort=1080` and `http.proxyHost=my-proxy-server`. When passed as Mac system level setting, socks proxy is seen as `socksProxyHost=my-socks-proxy-server` but I can't determine the equivalent environment variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the appropriate environment variable to set but found an alternate solution. Adding this to `bash_profile` works for me

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=1080 -DsocksProxyHost=my-socks-server"
```