# Xcode build upload Error: Outbound access to TCP port 443 and unable to find a MZContentProviderUpload for package. (1041)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode9.3

Xcode upload error:

The Following issue occurred while distributing your application.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, in macOS Mojave (10.14.2) with Xcode 10.1

It seems that Xcode application need to allow for outbound connection

**Steps to resolve**

1. System Preference -> Security & privacy -> Firewall
2. Click on Lock icon & enter admin's credential to unlock it.
3. Click firewall options
4. Check "Automatically allow built-in software to receive incoming connection"
5. Click "+" icon & add Xcode to it. (Make sure that you add correct Xcode version from which you are deploying build).

[image]

Comment: My firewall is closed. Is there any other approach to this problem?