# application loader stuck at "testing tcp udp connectivity"

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

you wont believe what I have been to so far, but to cut the story short:

- this mac is 10.7.5
- firewall is off
- I just downloaded Xcode with Application Loader 2.8
- no java has been installed

The program is stuck at "testing tcp udp connectivity" when uploading an iphone app

Comment: Please select Danny's answer as it is the most correct even if you did not go that path.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The second solution at [itunesconnect using application loader behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/ituneconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall) worked for me.

For reference:

> Go to Preferences, Advanced, select DAV only.
>
> This will use port 443 (aka HTTPS) for uploading.

Then use application loader to upload your application.

PS. For me it stayed at 0 bytes/sec for a good five minutes at the "Uploading package to the iTunes Store message", but given enough time updates at the 50% mark and then at the 100% mark. Leave it running for a good 10/15 minutes (depending on your app size) before you quit it.

Comment: This should have been selected as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it turns out the ports in this company's network are blocked, went back home and it worked.

Comment: Do you know which ports are needed?

Comment: You will find it here, page 8:  https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Comment: it appears that the ports are 44000-44100 and 33000-33100