# Error uploading ios application to itunesconnect "failed to open ssh session (16)"

Tags: ios, xcode, ssh, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am having a real repetitive issue uploading app to itunesConnect. It does not matter if I use "Application loader" or xcodes "Archive" utility, the result is the same ("failed to open ssh session (16)"). I am doing this on a Computer and network that was used for multiple uploads of applications to  itunesConnect in the past and never having this problem. I even uploaded an application the same day (without problem), but got errors for this app.

I reviewed the detail log and found nothing useful to determine why the problem would happen.

I posted the log at link bellow since it is to long to be posted here
http://pastebin.ca/2801584

I am using:
-java (1.6.0)
-xcode 5.1.1
-appLoader 2.9.1
-osx 10.9.3

what i tried already:
-checked and rechecked application meta data
-tried to upload via different network
-changed app bundle identifier (develop site, itunesconnect and application)
-tried contacting support via itunesConnect (with no response after multiple days).

I thank you for any help you can offer me.

Comment: Look this:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16514998/1213920

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the log, you don't have network connectivity to Apple's servers, so all of your connection attempts are timing out.

```
[2014-06-09 11:12:22 CEST] <main> DBG-X:   testing host/port: vgr105.apple.com/33001
[2014-06-09 11:13:38 CEST] <aspera.util.SelectThread> ERROR: The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session. (16)'

[2014-06-09 11:23:07 CEST] <Transport Protocol Seeker> DEBUG: Transfer warning: Unable to connect to sgr403.apple.com:44001: Failed to connect
    at com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferEngine$5.run(TransferEngine.java:3617)
Caused by: Transfer error: Failed to connect
    at com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferInstance.newControlPort(TransferInstance.java:367)
    at com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.ControlStream.<init>(ControlStream.java:894)
    at com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferEngine$Connector.run(TransferEngine.java:3185)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: connection timeout
    at com.signiant.mobilize.ddsclient.connection.Tcp.<init>(Tcp.java:47)
    at com.signiant.interactivetransfer.engine.TransferInstance.newControlPort(TransferInstance.java:361)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: connection timeout
    at com.signiant.mobilize.ddsclient.connection.Tcp.<init>(Tcp.java:42)
    ... 3 more
```

The simplest explanation is that you're being blocked by a firewall within your local network. If that is the case, then you need to contact your network administrators to open up the ports needed for the transporter to work.

The *iTunes Connect Transporter Quick Start Guide* lists the ports that have to be opened in order for the transporter to work. You can get the document from the iTunes developer site, or I found a copy online [here.](http://wmiphone.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/itunes_store_transporter_quick_start_guide_v2.pdf)

Comment: link with current version of the table directly from apple: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf (page 6)

Comment: link with the current version of accessible URLs:
https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdATD1E112-D1E1A1303-D1E112A1126

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the answer here:

[itunesconnect using application loader behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/itunesconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall)

In short, change Application Loader's Advanced preferences so that it only uses the DAV transfer protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this issue again and cant find a resolution. I had to re download the application loader and after the IPA has been created open up the application loader you just downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all sites are smoothly accessible from your Mac,

http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/e3#/itc8e7ec5a60