# Unable to upload app to iTunes Connect with Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, ssh, app-store-connect, xcode7

I am been getting this error with Xcode 7.0.1 uploading to iTunes Connect:

**The session's status is FAILED and the error description is 'failed to open ssh session. (16)'**

Seems to be a network issue (ssh) and the fact that I can upload from my home network.

I've used the Network Utility and it appears as if these are open:

- itmsdav.apple.com:443
- contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com:443
- idmsa.apple.com:443

However, I am not entirely convinced.

Also I've tried Application Loader using only DAV transfer protocol and get this:

**An error occurred uploading to the App Store**

I've also tried setting **https.proxyPort = 80** located in:

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/net.properties
```

Nothing seems to work. All of this started after upgrading to both Yosemite and Xcode 7 (about 2 weeks ago).

Thanks in advance for any clues,

Roger

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462385/unable-to-download-application-app-name-could-not-be-installed-at-this-time

Comment: `failed to open ssh session. (16)` is coming from the Aspera subsystem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120220/error-uploading-ios-application-to-itunesconnect-failed-to-open-ssh-session-16 and pay attention to the Aspera connectivity requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and I am sure that is the case when using Xcode.  As an alternative I tried the Application Loader using only the DAV protocol. That was still giving me an error. Is DAV doing anything with ssh?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, any solutions yet?

Answer (score 1):

After quite a lot of time, I have an answer that works for me.  I had tried both Xcode 7.0.1 and the Application Loader v3.2 that is part of Xcode.  Still having preferences set for DAV Transfer Protocol only, I downloaded Application Loader v3.1 from iTunes Connect. Go to Resources and Help then to the bottom and View Tools. The link for Application Loader 3.0 actually downloads 3.1, but that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I worked for me after I disabled the firewall on OSX.