# App Store upload is really slow and hogging my internet connection

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

In the past 6 months every time I upload a new version/build to the Apple App Store through `Xcode / Application Loader`, it takes between 20-40 minutes for even the smallest app. The uploader is always stuck at the beginning and when if finishes after a huge amount of time, the progress bar just jumps to the end.

[image]

Also, and the most annoying, **it totally hogs my internet connection (and anyone who is connected to the network aside from me)**. It’s not usable at all.. it’s really frustrating to upload a build to the App Store for so much time while it totally kills my internet connection -> it happens on any internet connection I try to upload from: Home, office, friends houses, public networks at the mall / restaurants.

[image]

When I upload APKs to the Google Play Store, everything works crazy fast (5-10min tops!) and my internet connection is working fine while doing it.

I also tried opening a bug report ticket to Apple, but because it’s Apple, they didn’t even take the time to answer it for almost a month now.

Does this happen to anyone here? Is there a way around it?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: It's really weird! I have been working with all this things for the last 6 years and I didn't have the same problem as yours.

Comment: How exactly do you measure the size of an app being uploaded? Do you use bitcode?

Comment: I ALWAYS have this problem unless I'm connected to a fibre connection - at home it can literally take hours on an ADSL2 connection.  At work the same upload was done in less than 5 minutes.  This problem has got worse over the last few xcode versions.  Google play is almost instant.

Comment: Mine too, I have a fiber line and my internet gets killed until the app is finished uploading. Which takes 15 to 20 minutes.

Comment: It's not weird at all.. Apple's infrastructure is big piece of crap and it was always causing problems to us. The reason is, that the server (or client, hard to say from the log) part (written in Java btw.) constantly timeouts and so the file is uploaded again and again.. It's really insane.

Comment: And the reason why the server timeouts so much is, that they try to send the app in multiple parts at once, but connection has troubles with so many multiple connections and these timeout regularly and must be resent.

Answer (score 9):

It is apple algorithm to validate first then accept application.

Sometime it uploads in 10-12 minutes sometime takes 30 minutes. It depends on internet speed, server load while uploading...

Developers working outside Apple have to keep patience, No Other way

Best is try to upload with Application loader.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18253670)

Comment: @kometen I'm sorry, but this is a valid answer.

Comment: @SmallChess it is not, see answers below

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was completely fixed upon updating itmstransporter.

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Please refer to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803 (look at KumobiusIvan's answer)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Step 0]First Export the ipa with export functionality of xcode and the upload it with Application loader

You can use this tool provided by xcode it self,

[image: Step 1]

[image: step2]

Comment: As mentioned in the question: Application Loader has the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I think sometime the internet connection works well, few ports in your connection internet setting needs to be open.

This might because of the Firewall issue.

We had similar kinds of issue in our organisation but then the link below was helpful for a work around.

[itunesconnect using application loader behind a firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/itunesconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. `fastlane deliver` worked for me. Still very slow, but at least it works and does not hog internet.
[Here the docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/)

Comment: The trick to get Fastlane uploads to be fast is to use the "Aspera" upload method by running it like so: `DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS="-t Aspera" fastlane run deliver ipa:my-app.ipa`. As an example, for me this brought upload times from 44 down to 8 minutes. However it might require a pretty open firewall as described in the [Transporter User Guide](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html#apdATD1E112-D1E1A1303-D1E112A1126).

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue while uploading build through Xcode. There was no indication or progress update while uploading build. So I tried uploading build through Application Loader.

While uploading build to App Store apple performed few checks like

**1. It first checks the valid profile for build on iTunes Connect. If there is any valid profile then we can upload build.**

**2. First thing happens while uploading build is verification of assets and also build validation by iTunes; this is the stage which consumes maximum time of build upload process.
(In my case it took 20 minutes avg. while doing it through Application Loader)**

**3.  Once verification and validation succeed build uploading starts. We can see the upload progress in Application Loader.**

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514998/2211019) use the Application Loader and uncheck the Aspera and Firmante options in preferences/advanced.

Probably is just enough deactivating the Firmante option.

Also check that you have enough ram for the app delivery. I recommend you to shut down Xcode and any other RAM intensive application.

Answer (score 1):

My situation is very similar to the OP.

None of the above suggestions work for me. Likely the real cause is physical and related how Application Loader is using the internet. I have ADSL2 connection with a Netgear modem/router assigning each device at home a fixed IP address according to the mac address of the network interface of each device. I had noticed that when Application Loader is uploading, my Windows PC could not connect to the internet. However, if in Mac mini I use Safari doing various things like watching video, my Windows PC can access internet.

Even stranger, when Application Loader is uploading, the modem/router could easily lost connection to the internet, as I could see from the LED lights of the modem. The connection is lost randomly at any progress of uploading the 20 MB file.

So I had turned off Windows PCs, iPads, iPhones and Android device at home, so Mac mini is the only device using the Internet, the Application Loading has finally been able to upload the app successfully in one go.

My guess is, my home phone line has some noise, and Application Loader is using the internet aggressively particularly the up link, so stressing out the modem, then causing other devices like my Windows PC lost connection, not even able to resolve host. When Safari is uploading video to App Store, no problem.

So my working solution is to make Mac be the only device using the Internet, given that the internet connection is already in poor condition with noise, near the edge of losing connection.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Transporter  app
you can download it from here https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10152019a