# Xcode Distribution failed with errors

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, sslhandshakeexception

Have been trying to upload my build archive to App Store Connect but encountering `App Store Connect Operation Error`

When trying to upload it from a different network it goes through. I have tried clearing the cache file located at `com.apple.amp.itmstransporter` as suggested in a few answers. Nothing seems to be working.

How can I get more logs / run the distribute step in diagnostic mode to get more information on the error?

[image: The following issues occurred while distributing your application.]

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443.

App Store Connect Operation Error
An exception has occurred: Remote host terminated the handshake

App Store Connect Operation Error
Could not connect to Apple's web service.
```

Update : If I try uploading through Transporter app it also goes through. Issue is specific to XCode.

Comment: It is probably outbound port filtering in your network. App distribution requires a number of ports open outbound https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069940/itunesconnect-using-application-loader-behind-a-firewall

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 if I try uploading through Transporter App from the same network it goes through. Hence checking how can I run XCode in diagnostic mode to get more logs on the issue.